# How to have the selected item in SwiftUI Menu shown correctly after selection?

Tags: swiftui

I have a SwiftUI Menu dropdown list that acts like a picker view for the user to select a weight. When selecting the weight, the menu goes back to normal but the selected weight is grayed out like it is not selected. So I encounter a UI bug. The weight should be in pure white instead.

I have to click again on the Menu and the selected weight appears normally and other time, it acts as it should.

How can I solve the way for the selected weight to not appear grayed out?

Here is my model:

```
struct Ball {

  var weights = [
    "12", "20", "23", "25", "28", "30", "36", "40", "43"
  ]
}
```

Here is my custom Menu:

```
struct WeightMenuPicker: View {

  let ball = Ball()

  @State var selectedWeight: Int = .zero

  var body: some View {
    Menu {
      ForEach(ball.weights.indices, id: \.self) { indice in
        Button(action: {
          selectedWeight = indice
        }) {
          HStack {
            if selectedWeight == indice {
              HStack {
                Text("\(ball.weights[indice])")
                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
              }
            }
            else {
              Text("\(ball.weights[indice])")
            }
          }
        }}}
      label: {
        Text("\(ball.weights[selectedWeight])")
          .fontWeight(.bold)
          .frame(minWidth: 120, minHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
          .font(.headline)
          .foregroundColor(.white)
          .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
      }
      .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
      .background(Color.blue)
      .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed variant (with force refresh for label). Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
Text("\(ball.weights[selectedWeight])")
  .fontWeight(.bold)
  .frame(minWidth: 120, minHeight: 40, alignment: .center)
  .font(.headline)
  .foregroundColor(.white)
  .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
  .id(selectedWeight)               // << here !!
```